# How to add a new element in case it does not exist in a ConcurrentMap while are using

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

I'm working on a Java development with threads and the truth is that I don't have much of an idea. It is being more complicated than I thought.

The thing is that I must group several objects in a ConcurrentMap, if the object is not in the ConcurrentMap must add it and otherwise modify it.

For the part of modifying the data I have no problems, but when I want to update I get a "Recursive update" error, I don't know what else I can do to modify/add my ConcurrentMap and make it threadSafe.

```
private final ConcurrentMap<String, Person> myData= new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

private void processMyData(){

 myData.compute(String, (key, person) -> {
        if (person== null) {
            myData.putIfAbsent(key, new Person("Antonio", 0, false));
        } else {
            //Update data, this part its ok!
            person.setConnectedHours(person.getConnectedHours() + 1000);
        }
        return person;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the key doesn't exist, you just need to create a new `person` object and return it.  `ConcurrentMap#Compute` will ensure that the entire invocation is atomic.
If you call `putIfAbsent` when key does not exist inside `compute`, it will cause an infinite loop. (The infinite loop happens in `ConcurrentHashMap#putVal` method).

```
        myData.compute("A", (key, person) -> {
            if (person== null) {
                person = new Person();
            } else {
                //Update data, this part its ok!

            }
            return person;
        });
```

See `ConcurrentMap#compute` JDK doc:

> Attempts to compute a mapping for the specified key and its current mapped value (or null if there is no current mapping). For example, to either create or append a String msg to a value mapping:
> map.compute(key, (k, v) -> (v == null) ? msg : v.concat(msg))

Comment: thanks a lot! finally a found the solution last night and I see this error, Its a beginner mistake jejeje thanks a lot zysaaa for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution last night but I forgot to answer this ticket.

I realized doing some very simple tests in a new project that I could make a put when I applied a simple lambda ex: (k,val) -> v == null ? " new text" : "modify"

then, I simply saw that I was not doing the return when I generated the new object so it was not instance.

A beginner mistake hehe but I hope it can be of help to someone who has the same error as me :)

Regards!

```
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Person> myData= new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    private void processMyData(){
    
     myData.compute(String, (key, person) -> {
            if (person== null) {
                return new Person("Antonio", 0, false);
            } else {
                //Update data, this part its ok!
                person.setConnectedHours(person.getConnectedHours() + 1000);
                return person;
            }
            
        });
    
    }
```